# Audience Builder missing

Tags: marketing-cloud

I cannot see Audience Builder option any where. Under my Audience builder app what I can see is only Contact Builder.

I was looking into this documentation
http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/audience_builder/

any suggestion help please

Answer (score 3):

Audience builder is a paid feature and will be visible only if the Salesforce has enabled for your organisation.

I would suggest you to  contact your Salesforce engagement manager to check if you have license for Audience builder

Comment: This, by the love of god, could sfmc just indicate in their help page that this is a "paid future"